# .NET Google API added refrences

Tags: c#, nuget, google-analytics-api

I've just added the google Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 from nuget.

It looks as it has added a fair share of new references to my project. Does anyone know how I can get the list of references that is added to a project by a nuget?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use source control?  Compare the before and after of your project's xml file.

Comment: You can recursively look at the list of dependencies at its NuGet page, e.g. http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3, but some of those might already be referenced.

Comment: Well, I actually do use source control - didn't think of that, it's not a bad idea. but I'm interested to know - didn't they make it any easier to find out?